# Strange Js errors on android stock browser

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, android-browser

During testing my web application on android stock browser I've found a lot of **randomly** javascript errors current formats

- Uncaught TypeError:Object # has no method 'xxx'
- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'xxx' or undefined

These errros appear randomly and not always, in different places.

In other androd browsers(Chrome) and desktop browsers everything works great without any js errors.

Phone:Google Nexus S

Android : 4.1.2

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: post ur code if possible so that we can see..

Comment: no need of full code... just snippets of line and related to that line...

Comment: I didn't understand question.For exmaple :Object # has no method 'append'.In jquery.js file

Comment: "android stock browser" is very vague. There's the AOSP browser that varies per each new release. Then there's the Samsung browser, and HTC browser, etc. You have to be more specific.